# Temporarily revert to git commit and push to servers

Tags: git, github

I have a project that want to revert back to about 12 commits ago. I want to revert back, push to the server and test it on production servers. If all goes well (the bug is gone), then I want to keep this version and dump the next 12 commits that caused the bug. If this revert process doesn't fix the bug, then I want to go back to the what is currently the head.

What kind of git revert should I do?

Comment: Are you sharing the branch in question with anyone else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this by creating a new test branch, and then nuking the 12 commits in question:

```
# from current feature branch
git checkout -b feature_test

# nuke 12 commits
git reset --hard HEAD~12
```

You can push this branch to the server and test.  If you don't like what you see, you can simply delete the `feature_test` branch.  If you do want to revert the 12 commits, then you can also remove the 12 commits from the actual feature branch using `git reset`.

If you cannot rewrite the history of the remote feature branch, then you can revert the 12 commits using `git revert`.  In this case Git will create 12 commits on top of the head of the feature branch which will undo the 12 commits you want to remove.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `git revert` with a range of commits, Git will produce a new reverse commit for each revert (so 12 commits in total).

Next, (optionally) you can use `git rebase -i` to squash all of the commits into one commit.

Finally, you push that one commit (or, if you skipped the squash, all 12) to your server.

Comment: missing the dump part (which could be as easy as `git show HEAD~13 HEAD~1 > /tmp/dump.txt` if the revert was also stashed)

Comment: @ThanksForAllTheFish I've read "dump" as in "throw away", in which case, all they need is to keep the revert commit pushed. (Alternatively, they can revert the revert)

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is

- backup your current state: `git checkout -b current_master_bu`
- get back to master: `git checkout master`
- then reset to commit you want: `git reset --hard <old_commit_hash>`

if this works, great! Push changes to master: `git push -f` (be careful rewriting history etc)

If you need to get back to your saved master you simply merge the backup branch:
`git merge current_master_bu`

Comment: you missed a fourth bullet, `git push -f`, to force push back to master. That is why I would not suggest this solution personally without knowing more about the OP's context (rewriting history is bad if you are unsure about who you are influencing)

Comment: @ThanksForAllTheFish fixed